Out Of Memory Error in Flutter using Android Device Emulator
I am connecting to supabase and fetching data from a table that I then pass through a function and display. I successfully initiate the supabase connection and retrieve the data, however, I cannot for the life of me figure out why when I pass the data through the function, the app stops working and I get a "Out of Memory" error. This doesn't happen when I use Google chrome.
To put it simply, the data I am fetching from Supabase is simply a List. After getting it from the database, I take the first date in the list and pass it through a function I called "dateListBuilder". Basically, all it does is take that DateTime value, check if it's null or not. If it is, it assign the start date as DateTime.now().copy(hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0) and then makes a list of 15 days of individual dates after the start date.
I tried flutter clean and flutter pub get. I tried removing the app from the emulator and launching it again, clearing the cache. I restarted the emulator and my computer, nothing works.
Here is the code:
void main() async {
  final supabase = await Supabase.initialize(
    url: AppSecrets.supabaseUrl,
    anonKey: AppSecrets.supabaseAnonKey,
  );

  final id = await supabase.client.auth.signInWithPassword(email: '************@gmail.com', password: 'test1234');

  final response = await supabase.client
      .from('workout_history')
      .select('id, dateCreatedAt')
      .eq('id', supabase.client.auth.currentSession!.user.id);

  print(response); // this is just a list with an id and a string
  // response = {['id':1,'dateCreatedAt':2024-06-08]}
  print(response[0]['dateCreatedAt']);
  print(DateTime.parse('${response[0]['dateCreatedAt']}'));
  print(dateListBuilder(
      startDate:
          DateTime.parse('${response[0]['dateCreatedAt']}').copyWith(hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0)));
  print(dateListBuilder(startDate: DateTime.now().copyWith(hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0)));
}

List<DateTime> dateListBuilder({DateTime? startDate}) {
  final zeroNowDate = DateTime.now().copyWith(
    hour: 0,
    minute: 0,
    second: 0,
    millisecond: 0,
  );
  startDate ??= zeroNowDate;
  final DateTime endDate = zeroNowDate.add(const Duration(days: 15));
  final List<DateTime> dateList = [startDate];

  do {
    dateList.add(dateList.last.add(const Duration(days: 1)));
  } while (dateList.last != endDate);
  return dateList;
}


dateList.add(dateList.last.add(const Duration(days: 1))); seems problematic to me

Ok I’ll change it and see what happens. Thank you.
